# HAVING vs. WHERE use case

Tags: sql, enums, where-clause, having-clause

I have a column that its value is set from enum.

I would like to check if there are lines that mistakely were set to a value nor from the enum, grouped by their value.

The following queries retrive the same results:

Using `HAVING`

```
select COLUMN1, COUNT(*) as cntr  
from TABLE1
group by COLUMN1
having COLUMN1 not in ('enum_value_1', 'enum_value_2')
```

Using `WHERE`

```
select COLUMN1, COUNT(*) as cntr  
from TABLE1  
where COLUMN1 not in ('enum_value_1', 'enum_value_2')
group by COLUMN1
```

What should I use?